# Flutter deep linking using gorouter plugin not working to redirect from webapp to Android app

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, gorouter

I've put deep linking into my app. If I launch links of the form:

https://edinburgh-guide-airbnb.web.app/Leith

It successfully strips the appendix out and opens the user in the correct place in my web app. But I want to be able to share URLs with users, if they have a native app it should open that using the deep link's instruction, if they don't then it should **FALLBACK** to my web app.

I've read the [Flutter's deep link docs](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) and added this to my manifest.xml:

```
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- Deep linking -->
    <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="edinburgh-guide-airbnb.web.app" />
    </intent-filter>
```

I believe this should hijack any URL with a body of `edinburgh-guide-airbnb.web.app`. It doesn't

I think my manifest must be at fault because the URL never triggers my installed native app, it doesn't even try to process the deep-link, instead Android skips straight to the web app. Which I don't think concerns itself with the manifest.xml file.

Is my manifest.xml formatted incorrectly? Am I misunderstanding how to intercept the link above^?

For completeness here is how my app processes deep links in my main.dart, using Flutter's [goRouter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router)

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return MyHomePage(title: "", analytics: analytics, observer: observer);
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: 'leith',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return MyHomePage(title: "Leith", analytics: analytics, observer: observer);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Did you find out what was the problem? I am facing exactly same issue. I have correct info in .well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: Hi Yawar, the comment below is essentially right. Please follow: 
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#web-assoc

It works often but I still find it buggy sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have correct assetlinks.json at https://edinburgh-guide-airbnb.web.app/.well-known/assetlinks.json
with

- app package name
- signing fingerprint

Comment: I have that. Deep linking rerouting to my app does work, but it's faulty. It only works if the app is not open. If its sitting in the background the deep link will bring the app to the foreground but it does not process the link and route the app.